# ExtJS Add IFrame to Tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I've searched the internet for a solution to this but haven't found one. I want to be able to send a request to an external webpage and put the response HTML into an IFrame so I can display it in a tab on a tabpanel. My current code looks like this:

```
onRpBtnClick: function (record) {
    var tabPanel = window.parent.App.Tabs;
    var tabId = "Rp_" + record.data.Id;
    var tab = tabPanel.getComponent(tabId);
    if (!tab) {
        tab = tabPanel.add({
            id: tabId,
            closable: true,
            xtype: "ux.iframe",
            title: record.data.Description + " - RP",
            src: record.data.RP.Value
        });

        tabPanel.doLayout();
    }

    tabPanel.setActiveTab(tab);
}
```

However, this causes an error:

```
VM534:3 Uncaught TypeError: c is not a constructor
at eval (eval at getInstantiator (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19), <anonymous>:3:8)
at Object.create (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
at Object.widget (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
at F.create (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
at F.lookupComponent (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
at F.prepareItems (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
at F.add (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
at Object.onRpBtnClick (MyJsFile.js:56)
at g.fn (ext.axd?7c77253627eb49df98537c540a08ec11:2)
at F.fire (ext.axd?v=4.1.0:19)
```

Comment: From memory, iframepanel is not included in the core framework. It's in the ux folder which means you'll need to pull it in.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Please post that as the answer